# Area of circle inside a square

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm doing a question where I have a circle that is inscribed in a square. In the gap between the outside of the circle and the inside of the square, a 2-by-4 cm rectangle is at the vertex.

I'm supposed to find the area of the circle.

[image: Circle inside square with a rectangle]

-

I know I need to find the radius of the circle to get the area but I'm sure how to get the radius. I wanted to exploit symmetry but I couldn't get it to go anywhere.

Comment: Hint:  Let $P$ be the intersection of the circle and rectangle, and $C$ the center of the circle.  Look at the right triangle with hypotenuse $CP$ (length $r$) and legs parallel to the square sides.  One leg is $r-2$ and the other is $r-4$.

Comment: The radius of the circle is $\frac 12$ the length of one side of the square. See if you can find the side length of the square.

Comment: @lulu That's pretty much the full solution. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Pythagoras Theorem and find the radius of the circle.
[image]

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that. I did try going the algebraic route (with $x^2+y^2=r^2$) but I didn't think of the $r-4$ and $r-2$ part